# Bike kit needs battery , need help choosing a battery and confused by specs

Tags: electric-bike, battery

I have a 48v 1000 Watt rear hub kit, with a multifunction LCD display.

Voltage:dc48v,Current:28A Booster1:1,speed set 1:1-42v/dual mode, brakes : low level.

Now I'm unsure what battery to get. Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried to read the manual or ask the seller?

Comment: Do please go browse the electronics SE site too - existing questions like https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/340770 and https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/105162 and https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/359047 and search out other relevant questions there.   If we migrate this question it will probably get closed there for lack of information.

Answer (score 2):

Reading what you wrote - you need a battery capable of supplying 48 volts DC at a current of up to 28 Amps.

The effective runtime will depend on the battery's capacity in Ah - if you want to ride at full throttle for an hour, you need a 28Ah battery.

The chemistry of your battery will have to match whatever charger you have for it.  A LiPO cannot be charged by your car lead acid charger, etc.

Physically, the battery needs to fit in your bike, so battery's dimensions will have to be no larger than the space you have available.  If your bike doesn't have anywhere to mount the battery then your options are larger, but you need to make something capable of retaining the battery and protecting it from impact.

Another Physical point, your battery connectors will have to be vibration resistant, and waterproof, and able to carry 28A of current.  Your wires will also have to carry 28A.  So for peak load, and assuming 1 metre of cable total between battery and motor then you will need wire with a cross sectional area of 8.6 mm^2 or AWG number 7 wire.

If you want 2 metres of wire in your system, at that voltage and current, then it has to be a cross sectional area of 17.1 mm^2 which is AWG number 4, which is 5.2 mm in diameter plus casing.  IE quite chunky.

---

Source - I electrified an old MTB, but that was only 36V and 250 watts.

If this all makes no sense, you might be in over your head and better off returning the kit for a refund.